# CSS grid layout 2 columns and 3 rows

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a grid layout with 2 columns and 3 rows but I'm unsure of how to position the grid items so that they are equal in dimension in their own respected areas (so that they aren't overlapping or taking up more space than needed). I've tried changing the sizes of the columns and rows using fr's and %'s but nothing seems to be working. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am relatively new to css. Below are my html and css files.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 20% 20% 25%;
  grid-template-areas: "health-pic health-text" "fitness-text fitness-pic" "mind-pic mind-text";
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.health-text {
  grid-area: health-text;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 65vh;
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: .3em;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.health-text h2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.health-index {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-pic {
  grid-area: health-pic;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.right-pic {
  grid-area: fitness-pic;
}

.fitness-text {
  grid-area: fitness-text;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-top: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 53vh;
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: .3em;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.fitness-text h2 {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.mind-pic {
  grid-area: mind-pic;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}

.mind-text {
  grid-area: mind-text;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 145px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2em;
  border-radius: .3em;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <title>Fred Ford | Health and Nutrition</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Navbar-->
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="container flex">
      <h1 id="logo"><a href="index.html">Fred Ford</a></h1>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section class="landing">
    <h2 class="big-text">"Don't limit your challenges. <br> Challenge your limits." - Jerry Dunn</h2>
    <div class="landing-pic">
      <img src="/img/landing-pic.jpg" alt="Woman stadning on cliff during daytime">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="grid">
    <div class="health-index">
      <img class="left-pic" src="/img/index-health.jpg" alt="Assorted healthy foods">
    </div>
    <div class="health-text">
      <h2>The Importance of Health</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat possimus consectetur error voluptates esse saepe quod quibusdam fuga maiores. Veniam, ea! Quod nesciunt libero, placeat atque suscipit excepturi eius blanditiis soluta sunt tempora
        possimus quaerat harum dolorem, id fugiat minima inventore exercitationem dolor dignissimos. Enim laboriosam animi minus facere! Officiis facilis nobis iste itaque ipsam aperiam modi, provident consequatur pariatur laudantium fugit doloribus?
        Veritatis deleniti amet nesciunt rem dolor impedit reprehenderit. Eligendi enim quos quibusdam assumenda praesentium dolore, pariatur sint cum consequatur rem non expedita quisquam ab earum cumque magnam sunt laborum necessitatibus magni ducimus
        id itaque. Itaque, corrupti molestiae!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fitness-index">
      <img class="right-pic" src="/img/index-fitness.jpg" alt="man working out outside in white t-shirt">
    </div>
    <div class="fitness-text">
      <h2>The Importance of Fitness</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Laudantium ipsam, ad aut, optio eos qui quaerat nobis et eum, natus delectus obcaecati! Culpa, voluptatum maiores? Repudiandae necessitatibus voluptatum facilis officia libero dolorem culpa
        illum cupiditate, quis sunt dolores quibusdam nesciunt quaerat quasi! Aliquam ratione quam praesentium animi obcaecati inventore ducimus eius aperiam, beatae maxime illum delectus, blanditiis eligendi quisquam molestiae et eum quia a. Similique
        magni eaque sequi quaerat? A ducimus enim delectus ea adipisci.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mind">
      <img class="mind-pic" src="/img/index-mind.jpg" alt="Man sitting on rock near ocean water">
    </div>
    <div class="mind-text">
      <h2>The Power and Nature of the Mind</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut, quae fuga eligendi, ipsum sequi ex molestiae quisquam iure veritatis iste ipsa nulla deserunt voluptas doloremque exercitationem voluptatibus odio ea repellendus illo natus! In ea consequatur
        excepturi minus alias cum assumenda commodi voluptatum necessitatibus vitae possimus ex qui sequi delectus facilis dolores, laboriosam nemo nam facere. Eos, explicabo porro cum nulla laudantium culpa id? Ipsam ut expedita incidunt, laborum vel
        nihil iure sapiente libero eius assumenda rem, animi laudantium ullam! Et, alias cupiditate culpa velit rem optio nemo tempora facilis vero sequi minus itaque, temporibus facere?.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--Footer-->
  <section>
    <div class="footer">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change from

```css
grid-template-rows: 20% 20% 25%
```

to

```css
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

Using 1fr for each row and columns mean they are going to have equal size

Previously you had the rows in `20% 20% 25%` to translate this to fr in units it means `4fr 4fr 5fr`

The fr unit is counted as the ratio of one of the row or column to the total fr
in the case of `4fr 4fr 5fr`

The first row have a ratio of `4/13`, the row column also have `4/13`, while the last one is different which is `5/13`

This means the height of each row will be different

When you do `1fr` on each row it means the ratio of each row will be `1/3` so it will be equal in size

Hope I helped you there

**EDIT:**

```css
.health-index {
  grid-area: health-pic; /* add this line */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fitness-index {
  grid-area: fitness-pic; /* this one as well */
}
```

You didn't specify which grid area the images belong to so it causes the image to span larger than the provided grid as it is not part of the grid